# Circle-CI Private Orb Job - use another public

Tags: circleci, circleci-orb

Am I able to use public orb commands inside of jobs of a private orb? I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it but my assumption is: "yes, you can" :D

As for any orb leveraging another orb's commands/jobs/executors, you'll need to add a reference to the public orb you want to use in the `src/@orb.yml` file with the `orbs` stanza, as you would in a `.circleci/config.yml`.

See [this template](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/Orb-Template/blob/main/src/%40orb.yml).

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Sorry, it looked like a file that we didn't use at all, and I am brand new to circle ci, so I was curious.

Comment: Happy to help! If you're not already using the Orb Development Kit (https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/orb-author/#), check it out.